# Zend mail adding double subject in the header

Tags: zend-framework, zend-mail, concrete5-8.x

While implementing the Zend Mail for the Concrete5 CMS. We are getting the double subject in the header of the email. Which is blocking it over the yahoo mail.

All other mail servers are working but yahoo mail rejects the email.

I found these URLs 
https://github.com/concrete5/concrete5/issues/5737
https://github.com/zendframework/zend-mail/issues/22

But the solution provided is not working.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the answer is to use only:

```
$mail->setSubject('My subject')
```

instead of:

```
$mail->addHeader('Subject', 'My subject')
```

That is, do not explicitly add the subject header; allow ZF to do it.

Is that not possible in your case?

Comment: Thanks David, That is an amazing solution. Although that did not solve my problem as C5 has a core helper for mail functionality which handles the Zend Mail in a manner where these changes are not easy. I had to implement core mail() function to get it working.